# Exclude sub sub categories from displaying in the archive page

Tags: posts, wp-query, categories

I have the following category structure:

```
Category x >> Category x Sub >> Category x Sub Sub
```

In my `index.php` file, I have created links to `category x` and so on.

So when the user clicks on the link in the main page, they go this page: `wordpress/category/categoryx/`

Only posts published under `category x sub` should be displayed here, the problem is that in this page, posts published under `category x sub sub` are also displayed.

In my `archive.php` I used :

```
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); if (in_category($cat)) { ?>
  ....
  <?php } endwhile; ?>
```

this correctly hides the `categoy x sub sub` posts in the main category but it also hides them from their own sub category.

So in this page: 
`wordpress/category/categoryx/category-x-sub/`

the posts published under `category x sub sub` are hidden too.

Answer (score -1):

```
/* exclude sons */
$_categories = get_categories(array( 'child_of' => 16));
$exclude = '';
foreach($_categories as $category){
    $_exclude .= '-'.$category->term_id.',';
}
$_exclude = substr($_exclude,0,-1);
$_cats = $cat.','.$_exclude;
query_posts(array( 'cat' => $_cats ));
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    ......
endwhile;
```

Comment: Never ever use `query_posts`, ever. There have been quite a lot written about just how bad it is. Also, Do not dump code as answers. Your code is confusing. Please file an [edit] and explain what it does and how it works